# Perl String remove a part of it after a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable my `$html` and it holds a string value. I want to cut it after the word

```
</SELECT>
```

How can I do that with Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $html = '<SELECT>foo</SELECT> bar';
$html =~ s{(</SELECT>).*}{$1};
print "$html\n";

__END__

<SELECT>foo</SELECT>
```

You should also consider using one of the many HTML parsers on CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

```
$html =~ s#</SELECT>.*$#</SELECT>#;
```

You can probably write it without the `</SELECT>` being in the replacement string, but IMHO it would be less readable.

Please note that s/// substitution can use other characters aside from `/` as separators, and in this case I chose to use `#` because your regular expression contains forward slash character that would otherwise have to be escaped making the regex less readable

Comment: If the $html string contains multiple lines, then the regexp above will only match `</SELECT>` if it is on the first line. You need to add the 's' modifier to treat the string as a single line. `s#</SELECT>.*$#</SELECT>#s;`

Comment: @Sam - I'm not sure whether OP meant line-independent or not... if line independent. you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regexp (power saw) when a knife (look for fixed string) is enough:

```
my $html = 'use dom to work with </SELECT> html!';
my $cut  = '</SELECT>';
printf "|%s|\n", substr( $html, index( $html, $cut ) + length( $cut ) );
==>
| html!|
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text which stands before the first `</SELECT>` you could use a regex like this:

```
$html =~ /(.*?<\/SELECT>)/;
my $required_text = $1;
```

or in one step:

```
my ($required_text) = $html =~ /(.*?<\/SELECT>)/;
```

It uses the non-greedy modifier `?` which I think is what you need.
Or better the `substr()` subroutine like the previous answer says.